# TypeError '_io.TextIOWrapper' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, random, collections, typeerror, deque

I'm coding a quiz and after the student completes the quiz, when saving the scores, I'm trying to ensure that a student's last three scores are saved to their names. If they haven't completed a quiz before, a new line is written for them within the the text file.

```
filename = (str(class_number) + 'txt')
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(name) + " : " + str(score) + '\n')
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
    lines.sort()

with open(filename) as f:
    f.seek(0)
    scores = f.readline()
    from collections import deque
    for line in scores:
        score= int(score)
        if name not in f:
            f[name] = deque(maxlen=3)
        temp_q = filename[name]
        temp_q.append(str(score))
        filename[name] = temp_q

    filehandle = open (filename, 'w')
    for key,values in filename.iteritems():
        filehandle.write(name + ',')
        filehandle.write (','.join(list(values)) + '\n')
    filehandle.close()
```

And this is the error:

```
f[name] = deque(maxlen=3)

TypeError '_io.TextIOWrapper' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign items to the open file object `f` here:

```
f[name] = deque(maxlen=3)
```

It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve here, but a file object is not a mapping (a dictionary).

You'd have to *parse out* the contents of the file into a dictionary first, make alterations, and write back the result:

```
scores = {}
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        name, _, score = line.partition(':')
        scores.setdefault(name.strip(), []).append(int(score))
```

This builds a dictionary mapping from name to a *list* of scores; since your file can contain more than one score per name.

Comment: I appreciate your help and if I implement you r code i do believe the code will run but what I am trying to achieve is that the last three scores are saved to a students name so if the Student enters an name that is already in the text file then it will simply add it on to the last score however if it gets to the point where there will be 4 in a file it will discard the first score and only save the latest three.

Comment: @user6173661: I'm familiar with the GSCE requirements for this task, yes. You'll need to figure this out on your own however; I helped you with this specific problem, it is a waypoint on the way to the full task solution.